# Why Concorrency Visualizer make my program efficiency abnormally

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2013

I tried to use Concorrency Visualizer to analyze my program,but I found my program efficiency is three times than without the plug-in.

Is anyone have similar experience?

I want to know how this happened.

Comment: It is standard Heisenberg, you change what you observe.  Like any profiler does.  Concurrency Visualizer asks the operating system to generate ETW events for very low-level synchronization primitives.  So it can visualize them.  That generates overhead on operations that are normally very fast, making your program run slower.  It is a completely irrelevant problem because as soon as you stop using it your program runs normally again.

Comment: Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle is absolutely not about changing what you observe :) It is a fundamental property of Schrödinger's & Dirac's equations.

Comment: Poetic license being used I suspect.